# How do LEA and others track no log VPN users?

Tags: vpn, anonymity, legal, facebook

Other questions have been asked but not with the specific details that I have shown (no log VPN, no leaks, dynamic user agent and JavaScript disabled).

Hypothetical situation
Someone sends a threatening message via Facebook. The criminal installs a fresh OS and encrypts their HDD. They then set up a no log VPN with dual VPN feature, so even their ISP can't prove they connected to that IP.

When I say a no log VPN I mean the VPN provider runs their servers on RAM disks.

They ensure the real IP can't be leaked (dns leak, etc) and set up a global kill switch so that no outgoing traffic can run outside the VPN. The Facebook account is in a fake name, set up using the VPN IP, same with the email associated.

The user goes a step further and starts using a dynamic user agent and disables JavaScript browser wide. How do LEA track people who do this, and how much effort do they typically put in to situations like this?

From my understanding the LEA would start investigations by going to Facebook and asking for an IP address and email linked to this account. The IP and email would lead to the VPN provider's IP.

The LEA would then go to the VPN provider and ask for all the information associated with this IP (connections, IPs connected, session times, customers associated with a connection on this IP).

The VPN provider wouldn't be able to give any information away due to the fact all their servers run on ram disks and they don't persist anything. They are at a dead end with the VPN provider.

They probably try and do something with the email, the email gives them all the information they have on them, maybe even force the email provider to keep tracks on that email but that doesn't show up anything that isn't classed as circumstantial evidence, not even that most of the time.

**To people saying "How logless the VPN really is"**

I understand many providers have been proved to lie about this in court cases. Let's say for the sake of this post that the VPN provider has been audited, had their servers seized and proved in a court of law they keep no logs. I understand that this could change at any stage, but again for the sake of this question lets say they don't keep any logs.

Comment: "so even the ISP can't prove they connected to that IP" - But they see that you connected to *a* VPN.

Comment: Sure, they can see you connected to A vpn but not the VPN  server (IP) that was used to send this message. This would probably be used as secondary evidence and I doubt LEA could build a case just on this.

Comment: All it boils down to how "logless" your VPN really is, and as a regular user, you have no way of actually checking that. Sure, a VPN provider may *claim* they don't store any logs, but that doesn't mean that there isn't a [Room 641A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_641A), where a LEA is listening. And since using a VPN means routing all traffic through, it becomes very convenient for them.

Comment: I've updated my question, for the sake of this question assume the criminal is using a provider that has been audited, and one that has had their servers seized and proven in a court of law to keep no logs. I highly doubt a case this minor would use any kind of interception, unless the message was used as evidence in a murder case or something much more important that a threatening message.

Comment: Extending my comment on the topic of Room 641A, the VPN provider in question operates under the jurisdiction of Panama and will not comply with requests from foreign governments and law enforcement agencies.

Comment: *"...how much effort do they typically put in to situations like this..."* - why should they put any effort in this in the first place? No crime was committed based on what you describe in your question so no efforts need to be done. The efforts depend on the actual crime, i.e. the worse it is the more efforts will be done. Also, crimes often leave traces outside the cyber space which you don't even consider but which LEA will do.

Comment: I assumed any crime that is indecent, grossly offensive, obscene or threatening/menacing, even via a text message is a criminal offence. Traces aren't evidence, and if no evidence can be found anything else is circumstantial and wont stand up in court IMO. Apologies if I'm coming off blunt but I'm just trying to get a technical answer.

Comment: @simonradcliff: *"... is a criminal offence."* - which says nothing about how serious a crime is. Again, efforts will match the impact of a crime. LAE has only a limited amount of money and people so they have to set priorities too. If humans are in danger then it is more serious but in this case it will very likely leave traces in the physical world.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Threatening behaviour via text is the crime as I stated in the question. Traces in the physical world wouldn't be very much without the LEA removing the anonymity of the digital user, they might have suspicions but without a evidence in the digital world they wouldn't be able to charge without evidence of the identity of the user in the digital world (IE, proving they sent that message).

Comment: @simonradcliff: I have the feeling that we talk past each other. I mean with traces that the crime has a manifestation in the physical world, like theft, harm done against humans etc. In this case this physical manifestation is the evidence and also provides clues about the potential suspect. While just threatening itself might be a crime only a comparable small amount of resources will be invested to follow this crime since there are enough more serious crimes.

Comment: I see what you mean, since this question is about the digital angle of it lets hypothetically say it is contained within just the messages and no further action is taken via the criminal but continuously threatening messages.